# Get a result of a column by comparing the condition with two other columns

Tags: r

I am working on my project and new to R. I have a data frame like this

```
#   AwayTeam  HomeTeam  TeamWon
# 1     A        B      AwayTeam
# 2     C        A      AwayTeam
# 3     A        D       Draw
# 4     A        E      HomeTeam
# 5     F        A      HomeTeam
```

From this data set, I want to find the result of team A like this

```
#   AwayTeam  HomeTeam  TeamWon   Result_A
# 1     A        B      AwayTeam    Win 
# 2     C        A      AwayTeam    Loss
# 3     A        D       Draw       Draw
# 4     A        E      HomeTeam    Loss
# 5     F        A      HomeTeam    Win
```

Comment: Something along this line might as well help `df$Result_A <- ifelse((df$AwayTeam=="A" & df$TeamWon=="AwayTeam"), "Win", ifelse((df$HomeTeam=="A" & df$TeamWon=="HomeTeam"), "Win", ifelse(df$TeamWon=="Draw", "Draw", "Loss")))`

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: This what I had done before asking the question `len.Res.D <- length(David.Moyes)
    for(x in 1:len.Res.D){
    if(David.Moyes$`Full Time Result`[x] == 'H'){
      HT <- ifelse(David.Moyes$`Home Team`[x] == 'Man United','Win','loss')
      print(HT)
    }else if(David.Moyes$`Full Time Result`[x] == 'A'){
      AT <- ifelse(David.Moyes$`Away Team`[x] == 'Man United','Win','loss')
      print(AT)
    }else if(David.Moyes$`Full Time Result`[x] == 'D'){
      print('Draw')}
    } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `case_when` from `dplyr` and specify the conditions.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Result_A = case_when(TeamWon == "Draw"~"Draw", 
                              AwayTeam == "A" & TeamWon == "AwayTeam" |
                              HomeTeam == "A" & TeamWon == "HomeTeam"~"Win", 
                              TRUE~"Loss"))

#  AwayTeam HomeTeam  TeamWon Result_A
#1        A        B AwayTeam      Win
#2        C        A AwayTeam     Loss
#3        A        D     Draw     Draw
#4        A        E HomeTeam     Loss
#5        F        A HomeTeam      Win
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(AwayTeam = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"C", "F"), class = "factor"), HomeTeam = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "D", "E"), class = "factor"), 
TeamWon = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AwayTeam", 
"Draw", "HomeTeam"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1","2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside using case_when you can go another way. In my opinion this simplifies the `case_when` statement. I used the `pivot_longer` function of `tidyr` to get which side the team is playing. Afterwards, I compare the side and the team which has won, where no team name has to be in the `case_when` statement.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(AwayTeam = c("A", "C", "A", "A", "F"),
            HomeTeam = c("B"  ,"A"  ,"D"  ,"E"  ,"A"  ),
            TeamWon = c("AwayTeam" ,"AwayTeam" ,"Draw" ,"HomeTeam" ,"HomeTeam"))


data %>%
    mutate(matchNumber = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_longer(c(AwayTeam, HomeTeam), names_to = "SideOfTeam", values_to = "TeamName") %>%
    mutate(Result = case_when(TeamWon == SideOfTeam ~ "Won",
                        TeamWon == "Draw" ~ "Draw",
                        TeamWon != SideOfTeam ~ "Loss")) %>%
    filter(TeamName == "A")
```

I inserted the column `matchname` to be able to find the opponent afterwards if necessary.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas and I have some columns with other data like goals, cards, etc. so ur code not worked in my problem.

Answer (score 0):

To add the column of `Result_A`, you can use the following code

```
df$Result_A <- apply(df, 1, 
                     function(v) ifelse(!is.na(v[v["TeamWon"]]) & v[v["TeamWon"]]=="A","Win", 
                                               ifelse(v["TeamWon"]=="Draw","Draw","Loss")))
```